# Can we access URL's path parameters in a Tornado RequestHandler?

Tags: regex, url, httprequest, tornado, path-parameter

I know that in Tornado one can capture some parts of URL's using regular expressions, but isn't there a more structured way to access path parameters? Maybe something similar to the way you access query arguments (`RequestHandler.get_query_argument()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Tornado doesn't know anything about what's inside path segments. The only way to access more detailed information, codified in path segments, is to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

All the path arguments are available in `RequestHandler.path_args`, or in `RequestHandler.path_kwargs` if you used named groups in your regex. See http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.path_args for more details.